# check if we are in a view context from within a model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, actionview

In my User model I am overriding the id like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    def id
        return "something"
    end
end
```

However I would like this to be overridden only if we are in a view context, otherwise if we call it from a controller or a model then I would like to return the "main" id

Is this possible ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this code? Is this for like url generation (where you want `/user/something` instead of `/user/1`)?

Comment: @SimpleLime Yes I just created a gem doing this exactly and the problem is when I try to update a record, the "where id = ?" part is calling the overridden id (which is "something" in this case) instead of the original id which should be something like 1 or 2...